# python3.8.2 telnet library - cannot get telnet read output on screen

Tags: python, telnet

I am using the following code with python3.8.2 connecting to Cisco network devices (switch, router), running in an eveNG lab environment. I am connecting from a mac laptop, to a router using telnet on IP 10.9.249.3 and port 32769.

Problem is that when I run this code I do not get any output. I can however see the commands being run and the running config output on the device itself using a separate connection. The code execution just stays put waiting for an event.

```
from telnetlib import Telnet

HOST = "10.9.249.3"
tn = Telnet(HOST,32769)

tn.write(b"terminal length 0\n")
tn.write(b"show runn\n")
tn.write(b"exit\n")

print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
tn.exit()
```

When I do a control-break I get the following output:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "p1.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/telnetlib.py", line 335, in read_all
    self.fill_rawq()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/telnetlib.py", line 526, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I found similar issues posted and tried their suggestions like changing to a different Telnet read_*() method but no change in the output.

One thing I have noticed is that when I connect to the network device, I have to do the following to disconnect the (manual) telnet connection:

```
ctrl-]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Thanks and regards,

Abid Ghufran

Comment: Do you get anything if you use *read_some()* ? Looks like it might be blocking while trying to read at least 50 bytes

Comment: don't you send `login` and `password`? It also may need to read data from device before write to device. See example at the end of documentation for [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html)